# addEventListener to many elements selecting them with class

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why when i click those elements with class click-to-open this function below does not work im trying to make something like a javascript accordion

```
document.getElementsByClassName('click-to-open').addEventListener('click', function(){
                document.getElementsByClassName('click-to-open').style.maxHeight = '40px';
                this.style.maxHeigh = '500px';
            });
```

Comment: Because getElementsByClassName return an array of elements, even if this is one, you need use event delegation for save resources and better performance, here and [article](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
var clickToOpen=document.getElementsByClassName('click-to-open');

for(var i=0;i<clickToOpen.length;i++){
     clickToOpen[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                        this.style.maxHeight = '500px';
                    });
}
```

The method `getElementsByClassName()` always returns a set of class array, if you want to target all the DOM elements you need to iterate through all of them, if you were using Jquery there is a much more elegant way to do it.

This is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2tx2s3rz/2/ showing the code

Comment: it still does not work and i want to attach this event listener to all elements with this class not just the first

Comment: @Georgi Antonov Try it now

Comment: its not allowed for me to use Jquery otherwise i would do it just vanilla javascript and cant get it work.
Your new code still does not work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2tx2s3rz/ look at the jsfiddle it works

Comment: @Georgi Antonov I have made changes to the code you can retry now I didn't notice you were calling the document.getElementsByClass() inside the eventListener